# tweepy stops after a few hours

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I use tweepy for streaming some tweet. This is my procedure:

```
import tweepy
import json

consumer_key = "***" 
consumer_secret = "***"
access_token_key="***"
access_token_secret="***"

auth1 = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth1.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth1)

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            print status.text
        except Exception, e:
            print 'Encountered Exception Tweet:', e
            pass
        return True

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print 'Encountered error with status code:' + repr(status_code)
        return True 

    def on_data(self, data):
        if 'in_reply_to_status_id' in data:
            status = tweepy.Status.parse(self.api, json.loads(data))
            if self.on_status(status) is False:
                return True
        elif 'delete' in data:
            delete = json.loads(data)['delete']['status']
            if self.on_delete(delete['id'], delete['user_id']) is False:
                return True
        elif 'limit' in data:
            if self.on_limit(json.loads(data)['limit']['track']) is False:
                return True
        return True

    def on_timeout(self):
        print 'Timeout...'
        return True

l = StreamListener()
streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth1, listener=l, timeout=36000000)

setTerms = ['enbrel']
streamer.filter(follow=None,track = setTerms)
```

After two / three hours this procedure stops. No signal error, timeout, etc.. It just does not get more tweet. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce this behaviour? It could have been a problem with your network connection, or Twitter's API having problems.

Answer (score 9):

Try adding an `on_disconnect` method to your class.  It could be that Twitter is disconnecting you (not an error, also not a timeout) and you do not handle this.  You can handle different Twitter errors differently, if you wish.

```
def on_disconnect(self, notice):
    """Called when twitter sends a disconnect notice

    Disconnect codes are listed here:
    https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/messages#Disconnect_messages_disconnect
    """
    return
```

Check out the [`streaming` module](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py) of tweepy for more info.

You can also try to enable stall warnings in your `streamer.filter()`.  Below are all the options and their default values from the Tweepy source:

```
def filter(self, follow=None, track=None, async=False, locations=None,
           stall_warnings=False, languages=None, encoding='utf8'):
```

Comment: An old answer I know, but could you elaborate on this a bit? I want to reconnect on_disconnect, but I'm unsure of how to best do this.

Comment: I figured it out: in my own loop, check for `stream.running`.  If it isn't, delete the stream and start a new one after `n` seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to initiate the api with a time out to start with

```
api = tweepy.API(auth1,timeout=60)
```